# On which systems/platforms is "%b" supported as a format specifier?

Tags: c, binary, printf, format-specifiers

I know that at least some implementations of `printf()` (or `sprintf()` etc.) support a `%b` format specifier, which formats integral numbers using binary digits. But - this does not seem to be part of the language standard (according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)).

So, which platforms / C-standard-library implementations support "%b"? And - can I test for this support?

I should mention libc6 on (fairly recent) Linux machines doesn't support `%b`; and that's what you get with gcc and clang on Linux machines. But maybe on other Unix'es, or Windows, or embedded libc's of some kind etc.

Comment: obLink: [Is there a printf converter to print in binary format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format)

Comment: Formatting for binary output is a C++ feature, not a C feature.  You can test it by trying `snprintf()` with a known (non-zero) input and test the return value (might be `-1` to indicate an error) and the formatted string.  You should do that at compile time so you can use a sensible fallback method to format binary numbers (or you could simply write and use a method to format binary values).

Comment: @jonathan: When did the C++ standard diverge from the C specification for printf? Or are you thinking of a specific C++ standard library which implements that feature? It's a go-lang feature. The glibc documentation has an example of how to use glibc's (deprecated) format conversion extension which implements a `%b` conversion, but it doesn't output in binary.

Comment: I've not formally verified that C++ `printf()` supports `%b`, but C++ does support `0b0010'1101` as a valid notation for a binary number (equivalent to hex `0x2D`), including the punctuation (which is optional).

Comment: Apparently you tried some major compilers already (please [edit] your question to tell us which), so what do you expect as an answer to "_which platforms_"? Do you want a list of more or less known compilers or libraries? -- At what time do you want to test for the support, compile, link, run time?

Comment: @thebusybee: Actually, I misspoke in that comment. Compilers don't support or not-support this - C libraries do (and compilers may or may not use their own bundkled C library). So, I'll rephrase that comment and my answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: 1. I asked about C. 2. I know that, but - you can't "formally verify" that it's supported, because AFAIK it's not. 3. On Linux, libc6 doesn't support `%b` (and that's the library you get with clang and gcc).

Comment: einpoklum, Note: there are standard [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641674/2410359) to using `"%b"`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Noted.

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"[W]hich platforms/C-standard-library implementations support "%b"? And - can I test for this support?"*

A: `glibc` has supported `%b` integer conversion since [version 2.35](https://web.archive.org/web/20221016003354/https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2022-February/136040.html).

I don't have a list of which C libs support `%b` and which do not. I know that `glibc` (post ver 2.35) does, and I know that the [`picolibc`](https://github.com/picolibc/picolibc) does because I *use* them (i.e. I'm not a *know-it-all*  :)

As far as testing, I guess there are two ways:

1. For `glibc`, check the version as follows; e.g.:

```bash
ldd --version
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u3) 2.36
...
```

2. For other C libraries, perhaps the best way is to compile a simple application in your preferred development environment; e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int int_val = 39;
    printf("binary value of int_val: %#b \n", int_val);

//  ANSWER: int_val = 0b100111 ; note no leading zeros

}
```